# QGIS3 missing geometry

Tags: qgis-3, missing-data

I sent a QGIS project to a colleague.  He tried to uploaded it on QGIS but got a error message in QGIS that the geometry of one layer is missing. He couldn't repair it, because the geometry didn't exist anymore. Do you have an idea what I can do? I checked the project but everything was alright.

Comment: QGIS projects only contain links to data, not the data itself. Did you send the data, too?

Comment: @Erik Yes, I did. I only have the problem with one layer

Comment: Was it a temporary layer? How exactly does the error message read? Have you tried providing the data again?

Comment: @Erik it wasn't a temporary layer. I provided the data again but I have not received any feedback yet.

Comment: @Erik it was just the message: upload not possible because of missing geometry

Comment: Upload to where?

Comment: What versions of QIGS 3.xx where you both using? It's not frequent, but sometimes what you packed with one version, another version will have trouble opening.